# HTML redirect for blocked IPS using htacess

Tags: ip, block, country

Looking for a redirect script using htaccess for a long list of deny IP designed to block certain countries but the list is very long

```
deny from 5.10.66.80/30
deny from 5.10.66.240/29
```

this is a very short list of what the very long list is but i want to redirect all dely to another site

I have tried the very long list of deny ips but it gives a 403 error which i prefer a redirect so they cab see that their country is blocked and reason why

Comment: Can you code a redirect for a single IP?